# Select Data Groupwise in sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

Hi i have a table `table_main` is

```
Item                   category
No People               People
Day                     Weather
Night                   Weather
looking at camera       Focus
looking Down            Focus
```

I want to bind this table in Gridview but only the rows where category is greater then 1 .
for the following table , gridview should be display as

```
Item                   category
Day                     Weather
Night                   Weather
looking at camera       Focus
looking Down            Focus
```

if `category` people is greater then one then it should be displayed as

```
Item                   category
No People               People
One People              People
Two people              People 
Day                     Weather
Night                   Weather
looking at camera       Focus
looking Down            Focus
```

Please help to bind these data as group wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_main WHERE category IN
(
    SELECT category
    FROM table_main
    GROUP BY category
    HAVING count(1)>1
)
```